# Python 3.6 variable annotations and numeric literals

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the documentation on Python in the section "What's new in Python 3.6" among other things there are presented variable annotations and using underscores in numeric literals.

However I tried shown examples and not all of them were passed.

Are these examples incomplete and do they require some additional code that is assumed under the hood?

For example this statement

```
primes: List[int] = []
```

issues

```
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

This statement

```
print( 1_000_000_000_000_000 )
```

is also considered as wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case works if you first import [`List` from `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List). Most types used with type-hints aren't built-in, they need to be imported first.

The second case also works if you are running under `3.6`. On my machine it correctly prints:

```
Python 3.6.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2017, 22:59:30) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print( 1_000_000_000_000_000 ) 
1000000000000000
```

If the error message you receive is: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` you're on `3.5` or less. If it's `SyntaxError: invalid token` you're not using the underscores correctly. I'm guessing you're receiving the first.

So, you might want to double check you're running with `3.6` (`python -V`).

Comment: I run the code snippet with the numeric literal on MS VS 2017 Community and it reports "One or more file in your project  contain errors. Do you want to launch anyway?" And if I press "Yes" I get the expected result. There is neither additional file in the project except the file with the code snippet.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow hm, if you are certain you're running Python 3.6 then this sounds like an IDE bug. Try running Python from the command line and see if you can repro, if not, I'd suggest reporting this.

Comment: I am sure because only this version of Python I have: "Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information."